# How to call a class method using an instance of a different class in Python?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, tree, binary-tree

I am a trying to implement a binary tree using two classes - Node and Binary Tree. When I am inserting the nodes (left or right), I am using the methods `insert_left_node` and `insert_right_node` which are `class BinaryTree`'s methods, but I am also using `class Node` to create a node. After every node insertion, the current object is returned.

Now, how do I call class BinaryTree's insertion methods using the returned object - current. E.g. In the second last line of the code, statement **`n3 = n1.insert_left_node(33)`** fails with **`AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'insert_left_node'`**

I need an alternative way to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = Node(root)

    def insert_left_node(self, data):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            current = self.root
            while True:
                if current.left:
                    current = current.left
                else:
                    current.left = Node(data)
                    break
            return current

    def insert_right_node(self, data):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            current = self.root
            while True:
                if current.right:
                    current = current.right
                else:
                    current.right = Node(data)
                    break
            return current

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = BinaryTree(34)  # root
    n1 = r.insert_left_node(22)
    n2 = r.insert_right_node(45)
    n3 = n1.insert_left_node(33)  # Fails
    print n3
```

Comment: If this isn't an academic exercise, you may be interested in http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/red-black-tree-mod/ .  Its primary focus is a Red Black Tree, but there's also a simple Binary Tree from which the Red Black Tree inherits.

Answer (score 2):

Your request literally doesn't make any sense. To achieve what you want you should just add the needed methods to the class you want to use. Try something similar to the following:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert_left_node(self, data):
        self.left = Node(data)

    def insert_right_node(self, data):
        self.right = Node(data)
```

Comment: that's fine! but is it possible to call the method using Node object?

Comment: @Shankar Yes, these methods should be called on `Node` objects, because they are `Node`'s methods. I.e.: your example will compile and run correctly.